# REGEX powershell script remove DEBUG markup

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powershell scrip test.ps1:

```
#if DEBUG
Write-Output "LOG 1"
#endif
Write-Output "LOG 2"
#if DEBUG
Write-Output "LOG 3"
#endif
Write-Output "LOG 4"
```

I would like a method to remove DEBUG tags with code between them.
I would get this:

```
Write-Output "LOG 2"
Write-Output "LOG 4"
```

I managed to lay this :

```
$src = "C:\test.ps1"
$out = "C:\test2.ps1"
(Get-Content $src -Raw) -creplace "(?m)^(#if DEBUG)(?s).+(?m)^(#endif)","" | Set-Content -Encoding Default $out
```

But the output, I get only this:

```
Write-Output "LOG 4"
```

I think this is because the command removes all that is between the first tag "#if DEBUG"and the last tag "#endif". Without considering other tags between.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why not just use a preprocessor?!

Comment: Replace your `Write-Output` with `Write-Debug`, then remove `#if DEBUG` altogether (simple search & replace). Make your script an advanced function, then use the `-Debug` switch to get your debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex like below,

```
-creplace "(?m)^(?:#if DEBUG)[\s\S]+?\n#endif[\r\n]*",""
```

Escape the backslash one more time if necessary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lA6rS5/6)